How to access all fields in Salesforce as a backup and archival system user?
We are running into instances when the data backup and archival system user even with system admin permissions is unable to access certain Salesforce fields and data.
At a minimum we would like read and edit access and all record type access. In an ideal World we could have a dedicated permission set that would grant access to all objects and field.
Is this something that is programmicatlly possible? I would not think so because even tooling/metadata API is derived from a user's access.

Please be more specific on what metadata the system admin does not have access too?  Sometimes, when a new SFDC feature is enabled, you have to add FLS for that new feature's fields to the System Admin profile
